# Is it possible to launch another app in my app and tap a specific coordinate of the other app with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Currently i know there is a way to launch another app in my own app, i am using the below code to launch Playstore.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.LaunchUrlHandlerActivity"));
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

My question is is there any way to tap on a specific coordinate or elements on the Playstore after i launch the Playstore from my app.

Comment: It would be easier if you just told us what exactly are you trying to achieve what is this specific component,